# How to redirect to modal?

Tags: 7

I use the module "Bootstrap Login Modal".

How to redirect

```
/user/login
```

to

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal"></a>
```

all over the site ?

Answer (score 0):

*Edit*

According to the Readme.txt,

> You should now see login and register links on the right of the main bootstrap nav bar.

Enabling the module should show a link on the nav bar by default.

According to the project page,

> You should now see login and register links on the right of the main bootstrap nav bar.

*/Edit*

You can update all the links on your content, or use Javascript on a page load to modify them.

If you want to go with JS. This should get you started:

```
  var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
    if(atags[i].href == "/user/login") {
      //Modify your links
    }
  }
```

Comment: My site works with the Bootstrap theme. What I want is that the "login, register and password" page opens by default with modal. Can I do this with my theme without using any additional modules ?

Comment: @Mathieu I updated my answer. Are you using the default main nav bar?

Comment: I want to have a link in the user menu. Here is my site s1biose.com